# Dynamically change size of splitContainer Panel

Tags: c#

I have a splitContainter control with two horizontal panels.  The top panel holds a patient identification banner and bottom panel holds related patient documents and a tree-view.

The patientBanner control is from the UK's NIH and if you click on a button inside the control (double-down arrows at lower right), it will expand to display more information about the patient's address, phone, email, and allergies.

It expands quite nicely, but I don't know how to make the splitContainer adjust so that the top panel can display all of the information.

[alt text http://www.intellicure.com/files/DocumentManagerScreenShot.jpg](http://www.intellicure.com/files/DocumentManagerScreenShot.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or anything that visualizes your problem?

Comment: Added the screenshot, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this. But, I think this should work
Make sure that you control is docked to fill the panel.

```
splitContainer.IsSplitterFixed = false.

splitContainer.DataBindings.Add("Height", <yourcontrol>, "Height")
```

Comment: I like the general idea of a DataBinding on the SplitterDistance property.  I'm using VS2008 and am not familiar with creating a custom DataBinding.

Comment: use the exact same code as I have specified. Dock your control to fill. 
splitContainer.DataBindings.Add("Height", <yourcontrol>, "Height")
<yourControl> is an instance of your control.
Let us know if you are not able to understand anything.

Comment: This was problematic in my specific situation, but I worked with the control developer to determine that there was a SizeChanged Event which I used to set the SplitterDistance to the Size.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

In the following code fragment I have  adjusted my splitter control. I have used my updated control's width to SplitterDistance. Hope it helps.

```
public DataTable GridView
    {
        get { return dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable; }
        set { dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
            splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = dataGridView1.Width;
        }
    }
```